# Solr Dismax handler - whitespace and special character behaviour

Tags: solr, lucene, tokenize, dismax

I've got strange results when I have special characters in my query.

Here is my request :

```
q=histoire-france&start=0&rows=10&sort=score+desc&defType=dismax&qf=any^1.0&mm=100%
```

Parsed query :

```
<str name="parsedquery_toString">+((any:histoir any:franc)) ()</str>
```

I've got 17000 results because Solr is doing an OR (should be AND).

I have no problem when I'm using a whitespace instead of a special char :

```
q=histoire france&start=0&rows=10&sort=score+desc&defType=dismax&qf=any^1.0&mm=100%

<str name="parsedquery_toString">+(((any:histoir) (any:franc))~2) ()</str>
```

2000 results for this query.

Here is my schema.xml (relevant parts) :

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords_french.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_french.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!--<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>-->
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords_french.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_french.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I even tried with a PatternTokenizerFactory to tokenize on whitespaces & special chars but no change...

My current workaround is to replace all special chars by whitespaces before sending query to Solr, but it is not satisfying.

**EDIT :** Even with a charFilter (PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) to replace special characters by whitespace, it doesn't work...

First line of analysis via solr admin, with verbose output, for query = 'histoire-france' :

```
org.apache.solr.analysis.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory {replacement= , pattern=([,;./\\'&-]), luceneMatchVersion=LUCENE_32}
text    histoire france
```

The '-' is replaced by ' ', then tokenized by WhitespaceTokenizerFactory. However I still have different number of results for 'histoire-france' and 'histoire france'.

Did i miss something ?

Comment: did you reindex the data after changeing from WhiteSpaceTOckenizer to PatternTokenizer ?? you need to reindex the data in order to see any changes

Comment: You're saying you have <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/> can you change it to <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/> restart SOLR and share the number of results for each query. If my guess it's true I will give you more detailed explanation later.

Comment: I changed defaultOperator and restarted solr. No change. Anyway I think Dismax handler is using "mm" (minimum match) parameter instead of default operator. Here I've mm=100% which is the same than having a defaultOperator="AND" for default handler.

Comment: If i use mm=0% (defaultOperator="OR") I've 17000 results for each query

Comment: I think DISMAX doesn't care about defaultOperator when building the query, and it sees "histoire-france" as a single word, and "histoire france" as 2 separate words. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3589

> With edismax mm set to 100% if one of the tokens is split into two
>   tokens by the analyzer chain (i.e. "fire-fly" => fire fly), the mm
>   parameter is ignored and the equivalent of OR query for "fire OR fly"
>   is produced. This is particularly a problem for languages that do not
>   use white space to separate words such as Chinese or Japenese.

It is fixed in Solr 4.1 (22 January 2013)

Answer (score 3):

You get different number of results searching for 'histoire-france' and 'histoire france' because query parser creates a phrase query in the first case, and a boolean query (separate  two words) in the second case.

This is not obvious behavior imho, but i believe it's hard to satisfy all use cases.

To make search treating 'histoire-france' as simply two words you can add "[solr.PositionFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PositionFilterFactory)" to the end of query analyzer like:

```
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PositionFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
```

Then search results for 'histoire-france' and 'histoire france' will be equal.

Note that position filter can be undesired for phrase searches (both 'historie' and 'france' to be present). Consider using of query slops parameter qs > 0 instead in case you have modified term sequence with say NGram filter.

Answer (score 1):

using `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`, Solr will split your query string into words.

But, after tokenizing you(Solr) split your word (again) into terms using [solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory). Look at the documentation and look at the Wi-Fi example.

That could be one reason, why `histoire france` and `histoire-france` are handled different.

2nd: don't forget, that the DSIMAX handles (normally) the query-term as "term" and also (additional) as parsed string again.

To solve your problem, you could try to avoid the world delimiter and try to handle "tokenizing" by using `PatternTokenizerFactory` (as you tried before, but now without WordDelimiterFilterFactory).

If that doesn't work, try to post the complete output of the analysys.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Enable the autoGeneratePhraseQueries to true and this would generate the phrase queries.
So when searched for histoire-franc, it would generate a query with quotes which will enable only the documents having both words as a phrase being matched.

```
<str name="parsedquery">(+DisjunctionMaxQuery(((any:histoire any:franc))))/no_coord</str>
```

Example working configuration -

```
<fieldType name="text_test" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Use query slop to specify the number of slops e.g. `qs=10` in a phrase query.

```
<str name="parsedquery">(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((any:"histoire france"~10)))/no_coord</str>
```

Comment: If I add autoGeneratePhraseQueries, a phrase query is generated for "france-histoire" but not for "france histoire". Suppose I have a document containing "histoire de la france". Then the phrase "france-histoire" will not match...

Comment: use query slop. Updated the answer.